# R HMAC-SHA512 signing

Tags: r, hmac, rcurl

I am currently trying to use a HMAC-SHA512 signing to get authentified on a website in order to request through the website api some personal details.

The website displays some code (but not in r!) for users :

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

I have tried to reproduce the code in r :

```
require("curl")
require("digest")
require(jsonlite)
require(httr)
require("RCurl")
```

The first step seems quite easy :

```
apikey = "2...XXX...3"
apisecret = "7...XXX...c"
```

First issue : I do not know how to enter the time, I assume that Sys.time() is not suitable here, nor as.numeric(Sys.time()) as it is not an integer (maybe I am already wrong ...)

```
nonce = floor(as.numeric(Sys.time()))
```

Then :

```
uri = paste0('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?`apikey=',apikey,'&nonce=',nonce)`
sign = hmac(apisecret,uri,"sha512")
```

For the two last steps, I have tried :

```
ch = binaryBuffer(uri)
curlSetOpt(ch, .forceHeaderNames = TRUE, sign)
execResult = GET(ch)
```

and got the following error message :

```
Error in as.character.default(url) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Does anyone noticed what was wrong with my code ? Any remark / question / suggestion will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me

```
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)
library(digest)

apikey = "2...XXX...3" #insert your key
apisecret = "7...XXX...c" #insert your secret
nonce=as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()));

uri = paste0('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey=',apikey,'&nonce=',nonce)
sign = hmac(apisecret,uri,'sha512')

ch = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(.opts=list(httpheader=c(apisign=sign)), .forceHeaderNames = TRUE, curl=ch)
ans = getURL(uri,curl=ch)
response = fromJSON(ans)
response$result #contains the table of orders
```